# Theoretical questions on functions in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Sorry for the poor wording as I'm not sure how to title this:
Suppose that $f$ is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{z_1,\ldots,z_M\}$, that $f$ has a pole of order $N_m$ at $z_m$, where $1\leq m \leq M$ and that $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=0$.

Explain why $f$ has a Laurent series in the form
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-N}^\infty c_{m,n}(z-z_m)^n
$$
in a punctured ball $B^{\circ}(z_m,r_m)$ for some sufficiently small positive $r_m$. What is the largest possible value of $r_m$?

Define $f_m(z):=\sum_{n=-N_m}^{-1}c_{m,n}(z-z_m)^n$. Explain why $f-f_m$ is holomorphic in $B^\circ (z_m,r_m)$ and why $f-(f_1+\ldots+f_M)$ is entire and vanishes at infinity.

I'm not sure of a good place to start here. I feel like the Laurent series should have lower bound equal to $-N_m$ instead of $-N$ since $z_m$ is a pole of order $N_m$...
Also, assuming that the lower bound should be $-N_m$, then I think the reason why that difference is holmorphic is because all the negative powers of $z-z_m$ will vanish and so $z_m$ becomes a removable singularity.
However, I'm unsure why then $f-(f_1+\ldots+f_M)$ is entire and vanishes at infinity only.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it says it vanishes at $\infty$ *only*. You know $f(z)$ vanishes at $\infty$ and so do $f_1\ldots f_M.$ Entire just means holomorphic on $\mathbb C.$ You can show in the first part that $f-f_1$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C \setminus \{z_2,\ldots z_M\}$ and $f-f_1-f_2$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C \setminus \{z_3\ldots z_M\}, $etc. (And of course you're right about $N_m$... i don't think $N$ is even a thing that's been defined here.)

Comment: Cool! Would I then have to show it is bounded and show it is constant by Liouville's or something like that?  
Thanks